# How to read only one line that too with a conditiion in python from stdin

Tags: python, stdout

I am passing the following data to stdin
stdout :

```
aa 
a
aaa 
aaaaa
[new,aaa] < name of the file with path ] 
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
[mod] <name of the file with path 
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
```

I want to copy only the name of the file with path from python.

```
if new keyword exists in stdin: 
      take the filename with path
else
      nothing.
```

Comment: Did you consider regular expressions? With that you can test whether a line matches a particular pattern and then extract the values you want from that pattern.

Comment: It makes no sense to read from stdout.  What do you really mean?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, did you actually read it after writing? The title makes no sense, but if I understood it right you probably need a regular expression and check for path in between [new, aaa]<path]

Comment: @JohnGordon Maybe they mean another program is writing to stdout and it's being piped to the python script.

Answer (score 2):

You read from stdin, not stdout. If you're piping another program's output to the Python script, it will be in Python's stdin.

You canuse a regular expression to extract the filename.

```
import re
import sys

regex = re.compile(r'\[[^]]*new.*?\].*<\s*(.*?)\s*\]')

for line in sys.stdin:
    m = regex.search(line)
    if m:
        filename = m.group(1)
        break
```